# How to open app after rebooting or charging api 27+

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler

The application should autostart after restarting the phone and when charging is connected, I did it like this:

manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".ChargingReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name=".RestartReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
          <action
                android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
             <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

RestartReceiver

```
class RestartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent!!.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context!!.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

ChargingReceiver

```
class ChargingReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Everything works up to Api27+. I read that on Api27+ you need to use JobScheduler, but I can't find information on my specific task, can this be done on 27+? If so, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine though few things to keep in mind for being able to receive these broadcasts.

1. Your app should have an activity that is launched at least once by manually clicking on app icon. This makes an app enabled so that it can receive broadcasts.
2. If your app does not have a UI then it has to be part of system apps which makes an anpp enabled by default.If in case app is not a system app you have to have a mechanism to make it enabled by sending custom broadcast or other means.

If either of the above conditions is true then only you can receive BOOT COMPLETE intent as per my knowledge.